# Listen to camera actions

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to receive an intent each time the user take a picture with the device camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. You can use a `FileObserver` to monitor the standard photo directory on the device, but that assumes that the app that the user is using is storing photos there.